# How to identify broken css line in wordpress

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, wordpress

I have a website called [yildirimakademi](https://yildirimakademi.com/) where I added a product to the shopping cart using woocommerce. This is displayed correctly on the right side of the navbar as a shopping cart logo. However, when I hover over it, I see that the photo is distorted
[image]
and the alert that appears when I delete the product from the cart is also distorted and appears in the navbar.
[image]
My question is: how can I find the source of this problem? I have coding knowledge but I don't know how to find errors on the frontend of a website. Could you please provide me with some guidance on this issue so that I can reach a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Just set this as custom CSS to get this https://prnt.sc/yycsR7FeekqK

```
.tinvwl-table-manage-list .product-thumbnail img, .woocommerce-cart-form__cart-item .product-thumbnail img
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: top;
```

You 're ready buddy! ;)

Comment: this worked! thank a lot! As a second problem, how can I prevent the messages in the navbar that appear when I take a product out from the cart? They should appear in the page

Comment: I have try to spot your issue but I can't see any problem. Can you please post a screenshot to understand better? Thanks!

Comment: it's the second screenshot in the post where I asked the question. Thanks a lot! @George Vasiliades
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhvUk.jpg

Comment: In this point I will not see any issue like your screenshot shows. But, let me tell you what I believe about this. Maybe you have try to compress compile as external file your CSS or JS with tools like LSCache or similar? If yes just clear your cache or visit your site from another and clear browser or just make a hit by pressing Ctrl+F5 2-3 times when are you visiting your site. Tell me if fixing after this!

Comment: After adding an item to the cart, are you removing it from the cart page that opens? Because otherwise it would be very weird. I am not using any cache plugin and I have tried it in browsers such as Chrome, Firefox, and mobile Chrome. I am experiencing the problem in the second photo in all of them. I am not very familiar with the frontend and WordPress mechanics, but when I delete an item from the cart, its JavaScript file runs in the 'woocommerce-message' div class inside the navbar, there is a strange thing there, but I don't know how to debug it. Thank you for your help, by the way

Comment: I've found a solution but I'm not feeling sure about this. I suggest you to ask the developer of Talemy theme for this. In fact you need to re arrange the specific div in another position like the screenshot here https://prnt.sc/nhYAiVRF16OP It's very easy BUT I don't know what can happen after this.

Comment: Also you re hosted in litespeed server so you have to enable the lscache plugin. After this you can set clearly any change and this why you have an final and well perfomed static files delivery

Answer (score 0):

form__cart-item .product-thumbnail img {
**width: 60px !important;**
vertical-align: top;
}

you should change 60px to 100% or just delete it